Call a Google Cloud Function from a procedure in Google Bigquery
I have created a cloud function called "process" from 2st gen. Now I need to call it from a procedure I created in bigquery:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `project-dev.dataset.testCF`()
OPTIONS(strict_mode=false)
BEGIN

  DECLARE response STRING;

  SET response = (

    SELECT *
    FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY(
      CONNECTION_ID("https://europe-west1-project-dev.cloudfunctions.net/process")
    )

  );

  SELECT response;

END;

This procedure returns the following error: Unexpected TVF argument type found, expecting literal, query parameter, or variable of type STRING
I also need to know if this is the best way to call a cloud function from biguqery? or if it is not possible to call her directly

The external query require a connection and a query. You didn't set the query part. And avoid the * in the select is you want a string

The EXTERNAL_QUERY requires a literal string or query parameter for the connection and query data. However, if you need to construct the query dynamically, consider using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to store it in a variable before execution.
SELECT *
FROM
  EXTERNAL_QUERY(
    'connection_id',
    '''SELECT * FROM customers AS c '''
  );

This post's answer section offers a concise comparison for reference.
See EXECUTE IMMEDIATE samples below:

How to declare a variable in BigQuery and set it as an argument for EXTERNAL_QUERY?

How to build dynamic query argument for external query?

How to use query parameters in GCP BigQuery federated queries


